# Effective solution for create array containing all groups in regex matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for an effective way to create array contain all matches contains regex groups matches.

e.g. Regex `/(1)(2)(3)/g` string `123` expected result `['1','2','3']`

My current code looks like this:

```
    var matches = [];

    value.replace(fPattern, function (a, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, s11, s12, s13, s14, s15) {
        for(var i = 1, v; i < 15; i++){
            v = eval('s' + i);
            if(v){
                matches.push(v);       
            }else{
                break;
            }                
        }
    });
```

It works, however I don't like the way how it does.

The first thing is that I actually don't know how many groups I will have in my regex variable `fPattern` so I need to define a lot unnecessary variables `s1, s2 ... etc`.

The second problem Is that I decided to use evil `eval` to prevent pushing this variables 'manually' one by one to array, maybe there is a better solution?

And one more thing - I did try use `match()` but unfortunately when I have pattern `/(1)(2)(3)/g` it will return me array `['123']` so it's not what I want to achieve.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Ok I found something which looks better

```
    matches = fPattern.exec(value);        
    if(matches && matches.length){
        for(var key in matches){                                
            if(key !== '0'){
                if(key !== 'index'){
                    formated += matches[key] + ' ';       
                }else{
                    break;
                }                    
            }                
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
arrays = "123".match(/(1)(2)(3)/);
arrays.splice(0,1);
console.log(arrays);
=> Array [ "1", "2", "3" ]
```

The `match` returns an array where the array index `0` will contain the entire match. From array index `1` onwards it will contain the value of corresponding capture group.

```
arrays.splice(0,1);
```

would remove the index `0` element, the entire match from the array, The resulting array will only contain teh capture group values

Comment: Thanks, I spent unnecessary on hour working on this code because I added '/g' on the end of the regex and match returns for me only one position in array.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`RegExp.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and collect its return values, which consist of the main match, the capturing groups and the starting index of the main match.

```
function findall(re, input) {
    // Match only once for non global regex
    // You are free to modify the code to turn on the global flag
    // and turn it off before return
    if (!re.global) {
        return input.match(re);
    } else {
        re.lastIndex = 0;
    }

    var arr;
    var out = [];

    while ((arr = re.exec(input)) != null) {
        delete arr.input; // Don't need this
        out.push(arr);

        // Empty string match. Need to advance lastIndex
        if (arr[0].length == 0) {
            re.lastIndex++;
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems that this answer is a bit off from what OP wants, but I will leave it here, for my own use in the future.

Answer (score 1):

A less stateful / more functional solution might be something like this:

```
function findInString(string, pattern) {
   return string.split('').filter(function (element) {
      return element.match(pattern)
   })
}
```

Takes in a string to search through and regex literal, returns an array of the matched elements. So, for example:

```
var foo = '123asfasff111f6';

findInString(foo, /\d/g)
```

will return `[ '1', '2', '3', '1', '1', '1', '6' ]`, which *seems* to be what you're looking for(?).(at least, based on the below)

> e.g. Regex /(1)(2)(3)/g string 123 expected result ['1','2','3']

You can pass in whatever regex literal you want and it should act on every item in the array and return it if matched. I'd go with something like this if you want to easily be able to reason about state/might have to re-use it later to match a different pattern. The question was  a little fuzzy for me, so your exact needs might be slightly different -- tried to go off what your expected inputs and outputs were.